# Column headers not being displayed in APEX in Classic Report

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am creating a page with a dropdown, from which the user can select a table name. After submitting, I am using a Classic report to display data from the table which the user has selected. The data is being displayed correctly but the column headers are not visible. They appear as col1 col2 col3 etc..

The Classic report is based on the following PLSQL procedure:

`return 'select * from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name(:P2_TABLES);`
where `P2_TABLES` is the dropdown to select a table name.

I want the respective column headers to be displayed instead of col1 col2. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting Heading type as 'Columns' in Attributes helped me displaying the column names appropriately.